# Horizontal navigation bar when resizeing browser window going wrong

Tags: html, css

my problem is when i minimize the browser window the horizontal navigation bar starts to go back into a vertical navigation and i don't want this. I tried the min-width and max-width but it did not help my problem or else i was just applying it wrong.
This is the html:

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
  <!--Navigation Bar-->
  <div id="nav" class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">******</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">*********</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">****</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">***********</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">*********</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my Css is:

```
#nav {
  position:fixed;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  height:110px;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:10px;
  font-size:30px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#nav ul li {
  float:left;
  border-radius:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
  border:2px solid #000000;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow:7px 7px 3.5px #000000;
}
#nav ul li a {
  display: block; 
  padding:10px 70px;
  color: #ff0000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

any one able to help me.

Comment: If the nav should be horizontal all the time no matter the veiwport, @media query is of no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#nav { white-space: nowrap; }
```

if what you really want is to force the nav to be horizontal all the time.